# Asp.net authentication redirect creating issue in custom asp.net mvc redirect code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We were using code snippet `return Redirect(redirectUrl);` to redirect the user to site home page after successful authentication. (redirectUrl is the home page url). The code suddenly stopped working without any change made in the project.
On analysis we found that there was some issue with asp.net authentication redirect and updated the code to suppress the form authentication redirect and the issue got resolved.

Previous code which stopped working:

```cs
return Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Updated code:

```cs
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
return Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

We need to understand why suddenly asp.net authentication redirect created issue in custom redirect even though there was no code change made in this file.

Can someone let us know what latest changes were made for the ASP.NET framework which might have lead to the issue. We are using asp.net framework 4.7.1 in our project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net websites can also be affected by IIS settings. In this particular case, the fix you found would indicate that Forms Authentication has been enabled in IIS. Typically this results in a change to your web.config file on the web server.

Comparing that file to the web.config file in your project may reveal what has been changed. Other than that, you've not given much detail to help anyone viewing your question to provide a definitive answer.